# GraphQL and MongoDB - getting the "createdAt" field from the data that was automatically inserted from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

Lets say I have model:

```
const SomeSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: String,
  },
  {timestamps: true},
);
```

This has the timestamps, which inserts `createdAt` and `updatedAt` into mongoDB automatically when I perform a mutation.

In my GraphQL type:

```
const SomeType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "SomeType",
  fields: () => ({
    _id: { type: GraphQLID },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
  })
});
```

I don't have a createdAt or updatedAt field, because mongoDB took care of it for me.

How would I get the `createdAt` value if I'm using `useQuery`?

```
const GET_SOME = gql`
  query($name: String) {
    some(name: $name) {
      _id
      createdAt // how would I need to call this?
    }
  }
`;
```

Do I need to insert `createdAt` into `SomeType` fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CreatedAt` as `GraphQLString` type, and insert into `SomeType` fields.

**Try this:**

```
const SomeType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "SomeType",
  fields: () => ({
    _id: { type: GraphQLID },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    createdAt : { type : GraphQLString }
  })
});
```